# Sentiment analysis histogram of a movie soundtrack

Tags: audio, sentiment-analysis

I want to generate a happy/sad histogram of a movie.

The program would analyze the music to find out whether it is happy music or sad music, and perhaps also analyze voices/laughs/cries.

The movie I want to analysis is the [French New Wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_New_Wave) 1961 movie [Lola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lola_%281961_film%29) if that matters.

Free, or at least free trial.